# semaphore_wait_trap when accessing class singleton using Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm running into a strange problem. I can access my classes singleton instance just fine, but if I try to access it again it just appears to hang. Here is a simple version of the code:

```
private let _SharedInstance = MyManager()

class MyManager: NSObject {

    class var sharedInstance: MyManager {
        return _SharedInstance
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        println("init")

        println(self.accessToken())
        println(MyManager)
        println("test 1")
        println(MyManager.sharedInstance)
        println("test 2")
    }

}
```

In this case it is calling it from within the `init` of itself, but it happens elsewhere.

The code never gets to `test 2`. As soon as it access `MyManager.sharedInstance` it hangs. No errors or warnings.

If I pause the debugger I can see it is currently having on `semaphore_wait_trap`

Picture (difference class names):

[image: Stack trace]

Restarting Xcode or the computer hasn't helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When MyManager gets created, a lock is used to prevent other threads from accessing the variable while it is being created. You cannot access this variable from within the init method. It doesn't just *seem* to hang your program, it will every single time hang your program because you are creating a deadlock.

Solution: Don't use that variable from your init method. Don't access _SharedInstance from your init method, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to be smart and set all the setup logic in `init`, but it was eventually trying to access the `sharedInstance` again.